# What is the best architecture for a Node+react js based enterprise level application..?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, architecture

I am new to Node and react js and i need to build an application using both of them. So i have 2 ways to build this application :

1. Separate Node and react setup : All frontend development in react js setup with a separate Node js setup for server.
2. Combine Node with react js : Integrate react in Node js and build application with this combination.

This application is going to have lots of hits and i want to know which architecture will perform better :

React send request to Node internally (in architecture 1), will it make it slow..??

Please advice..!!

Comment: "Best" is totally subjective.

Comment: I was also looking for a similar thing and came across with a good tut, It might be helpful if you haven't seen yet:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/react-on-the-server-for-beginners-build-a-universal-react-and-node-app

Answer (score 2):

Your React app will need to send requests to your Node app anyway, now matter if you combine the two or not.

I always recommend building the frontend and backend separately for few reasons. First, you will need to think about and hopefully document the API that will connect both of those projects, with no ad hoc changes to the backend every time you make changes to the frontend and vice versa. And also you will be able to more easily add other frontends, like a mobile app or a desktop application if you have a well defined API.

But you can also do it the other way and have a more monolithic application that would still consist of frontend and backend parts but more tightly coupled. And whether or not a clear abstraction boundary and loose coupling is an advantage worth putting a little bit more design into the entire project is entirely up to you. It usually pays off after some time when your application gets complex and when you want to add mobile application or other frontends.